# Is it trademark infringement if you put the word 'the' in front?

Tags: copyright, trademark, trade-name

There is a trademarked company by the name "good vibe tribe", registered for "Hosting an online community web site featuring the bringing of people together for the common good and challenges them to do good deeds in their community".

Is "the good vibe tribe" sign different enough to be legally sold on my print on demand business merch?

Comment: If you want to know whether you can use that phrase on your marketing merchandise, you should ask a trademark lawyer in your jurisdiction.  The main question the lawyer will have to address is whether your use of the trademark would confuse consumers.  This in turn raises the question of how similar your businesses are.  For example, if you want to manufacture hammers under the _Diamond_ trademark, you probably won't violate the _Diamond_ trademark of an accounting services company, but you might violate the _Diamond_ trademark of a household appliance manufacturer.

Answer (score 4):

### No

Minor changes to trade marks are still the same trade mark.

Comment: If used in the same or confusingly similar field.

Answer (score 4):

The legal question is likelihood of confusion, in this case, confusion over the belief that the product is endorsed or affiliated with the "good vibe tribe" that holds that trademark. A wide variety of factual details could sway that one way or the other.